# Sklearn cosine similarity for strings, Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, string-matching

I am writing an algorithm that checks how much a string is equal to another string. I am using Sklearn cosine similarity.

My code is:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

example_1 = ("I am okey", "I am okeu")
example_2 = ("I am okey", "I am crazy")

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(example_1)
result_cos = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[0:1], tfidf_matrix)
print(result_cos[0][1])
```

Running this code for example_1, prints 0.336096927276. Running it for example_2, it prints the same score. The result is the same in both cases because there is only one different word.

What I want is to get a higher score for example_1 because the different words "okey vs okeu" have only one different letter. In contrast in example_2 there are two completely different words "okey vs crazy".

How can my code take in consideration that in some cases the different words are not completely different?

Answer (score 4):

For short strings, [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) will probably yield better results than cosine similarity based on words. The algorithm below is adapted from [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Python). Since this is a distance metric, smaller score is better.

```
def levenshtein(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) < len(s2):
        s1, s2 = s2, s1

    if len(s2) == 0:
        return len(s1)

    previous_row = range(len(s2) + 1)
    for i, c1 in enumerate(s1):
        current_row = [i + 1]
        for j, c2 in enumerate(s2):
            insertions = previous_row[j + 1] + 1
            deletions = current_row[j] + 1
            substitutions = previous_row[j] + (c1 != c2)
            current_row.append(min(insertions, deletions, substitutions))
        previous_row = current_row

    return previous_row[-1]/float(len(s1))

example_1 = ("I am okey", "I am okeu")
example_2 = ("I am okey", "I am crazy")

print(levenshtein(*example_1))
print(levenshtein(*example_2))
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but `from leven import levenshtein` would be easier.

Comment: My strings are product titles. I am trying to combine 3 different metrics. Levenshtein, cosine and jaro winkler, I am calculating the mean of these 3 metrics.