# calculating the dot product using sklearn's linear_kernel()

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, recommendation-engine

I have an error of array is too big while calculating the dot product of an array.

The Data sample is:

```
metadata['overview'].head()
out: 0    Led by Woody, Andy's toys live happily in his ...
1    When siblings Judy and Peter discover an encha...
2    A family wedding reignites the ancient feud be...
3    Cheated on, mistreated and stepped on, the wom...
4    Just when George Banks has recovered from his ...
Name: overview, dtype: object
```

Use TF-IDF Vectorizer, This will give a matrix where each column represents a word in the overview vocabulary and each column represents a movie.

```
#Define a TF-IDF Vectorizer Object. Remove all english stop words such as 'the', 'a'
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
#Replace NaN with an empty string
metadata['overview'] = metadata['overview'].fillna('')
#Construct the required TF-IDF matrix by fitting and transforming the data
tfidf_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(metadata['overview'])
#Output the shape of tfidf_matrix
tfidf_matrix.shape
out[3]: (45466, 75827)
```

I am using Sklearn class

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel
# Compute the cosine similarity matrix
cosine_sim = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)
```

by running this line i got following error:

```
ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.
```

Can anyone guide me how can i solve this error ?

Comment: The first dimension of the matrix is the samples or the features ?

Comment: @sera I have updated my code above please take a look

Comment: okay. so in the tfidf_matrix you have strings ? is there the possibility to upload the data ? i could try to reproduce the error.

Comment: @sera Yes its strings, i have updated my question with sample data, its just head i have .csv with movie data which i am using.

Comment: not sure if sample is good enough or you need complete data file in any case i use this site to get data: 
https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/

Comment: can you use this and let me know (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html)

Comment: see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728069/sklearn-cosine-similarity-for-strings-python

Comment: Already tried your first sugesstion and it gives Memory Error and ssecond doesn't give me the cosine similarity score which i actually need to proceed further, check this tutorial which i am following:
https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/recommender-systems-python